# MSVC Linkage error while building used unimplemented functions

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, linker, shared-libraries

Consider this tiny library:
**lib.hh**:

```cpp
#ifdef WIN32
    #ifdef BUILDING
        #define EXPORT_THIS __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define EXPORT_THIS __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#elif defined(__linux__)
    #define EXPORT_THIS extern "C"
#endif

EXPORT_THIS void Function();
void UseThatFunction();
```

**lib.cc**:

```cpp
#include "lib.hh"

void UseThatFunction() { Function(); }
```

build with:

```
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS on)
add_library(ThatLibrary SHARED lib.cc lib.hh)
target_compile_definitions(ThatLibrary PRIVATE BUILDING)

add_subdirectory(backend)
```

Using like this:
**using.cc**

```cpp
#include "../lib.hh"
void EXPORT_THIS Function() { /* implementation */ }
```

build with:

```
add_library(UsingThatLibrary SHARED using.cc)
target_link_libraries(UsingThatLibrary PUBLIC
  ThatLibrary
)
```

This works fine with GCC, but fails with MSVC:

```
lib.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl Function(void)" (?Function@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl UseThatFunction(void)" (?UseThatFunction@@YAXXZ)
```

How could I fix it?

EDIT: Building the `lib` staticaly works fine. But what is wrong with the shared version?

---

Restriction:

- I couldn't have virtual functions.
- It's also impossible to implement `UseThatFunction` on the user side.
- It should build with both GCC(>=11) and MSVC(>=2020).

Comment: You should have `target_link_libraries(UsingThatLibrary PUBLIC ThatLibrary)` not `target_compile_definitions(UsingThatLibrary PUBLIC
  ThatLibrary
)`

Comment: Also there is [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html) which you may consider using for the macro used for exporting.

Comment: @drescherjm, I just wanted to have a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You should add CMake to the question tags as apparently you are using CMake (and the issue probably is in how you set up your project in CMake).